# Unable to Login to Hybris Mobile iOS B2B Application

Tags: ios, authentication, oauth, sap-commerce-cloud, b2b

I am unable to login into Hybris Mobile App SDK for iOS. I am using the default B2B sample application provided by Hybris in the iOS SDK.

I have setup the Hybris Platform on my machine and have set the IP Address, Port and username into the Environments.plist file.
Default username for B2B is mark.rivers@pronto-hw.com and Password: 12341234

Below is the error:

2016-09-07 18:19:45:445 yB2BApp[20152:70b] Login button pressed ...

2016-09-07 18:19:47.197 yB2BApp[20152:291779] Retrieving a first time token for the user mark.rivers@pronto-hw.com

2016-09-07 18:19:47:198 yB2BApp[20152:70b] injectAuthorizationHeader Basic bWFyay5yaXZlcnNAcHJvbnRvLWh3LmNvbToxMjM0MTIzNA==

2016-09-07 18:19:47:198 yB2BApp[20152:70b] url https://:9002/authorizationserver/oauth/token
2016-09-07 18:19:47:198 yB2BApp[20152:70b] params

```
{
"client_id" = "mobile_android";
"client_secret" = secret;
"grant_type" = password;
password = 12341234;
username = "mark.rivers@pronto-hw.com";
}
```

2016-09-07 18:19:47:317 yB2BApp[20152:70b] Error during retrieval of the token: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: unauthorized (401)" UserInfo=0x7b86e6e0

{com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response= { URL: https://:9002/authorizationserver/oauth/token } { status code: 401, headers {

```
"Content-Type" = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
Date = "Wed, 07 Sep 2016 12:49:47 GMT";
Server = "Apache-Coyote/1.1";
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
"X-Frame-Options" = SAMEORIGIN;
```

} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://:9002/authorizationserver/oauth/token, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unauthorized (401), com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<7b0d0a20 20202265 72726f72 7322203a 205b207b 0d0a2020 20202020 226d6573 73616765 22203a20 22556e6b 6e6f776e 20636c69 656e7420 6d6f6269 6c655f61 6e64726f 6964222c 0d0a2020 20202020 22747970 6522203a 2022556e 61757468 6f72697a 65644572 726f7222 0d0a2020 207d205d 0d0a7d>}

2016-09-07 18:19:47:318 yB2BApp[20152:70b] Problems during the auth token retrieval, reason: Request failed: unauthorized (401)

2016-09-07 18:19:47:630 yB2BApp[20152:70b] Error retrieved ...

Also in code there is a method applyBasicAuth which is adding authorizationHeader and the BASIC_AUTH is constant instead based on password. Is this supposed to change:

```
- (void)applyBasicAuth {
    if(self.restEngine) {
        NSString *authorizationHeader = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", BASIC_AUTH];
        [self.restEngine injectAuthorizationHeader:authorizationHeader];
    } else {
        DDLogError(@"!!! RestEngine not set !!!");
    }
}
```

BASIC_AUTH is:

```
#define BASIC_AUTH @"bW9iaWxlX2FuZHJvaWQ6c2VjcmV0"
```

**Environments.plist screenshot:**

[image]

**Error Screenshot:**

[image]

Postman Results:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Hybris Console Logs:**

ERROR [hybrisHTTP20] [xx.xxx.xx.xxx] [ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter] An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: Unknown client mobile_ios
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:110) ~[spring-security-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:132) ~[spring-security-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156) ~[spring-security-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter.attemptAuthentication(ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter.java:123) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.6.RELEASE
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEAS
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELE
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:224) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.filter.AnonymousClientFilter.doFilter(AnonymousClientFilter.java:91) [webservicescommonsserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:224) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:71) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:224) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.TenantActivationFilter.doFilter(TenantActivationFilter.java:89) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:224) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.Log4JFilter.doFilter(Log4JFilter.java:45) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:224) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain.doFilterInternal(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:154) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.59]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.59]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.59]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.59]
        at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.filter.SessionHidingFilter.doFilter(SessionHidingFilter.java:44) [webservicescommonsserver.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.59]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.59]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.XSSFilter.processPatternsAndDoFilter(XSSFilter.java:293) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:247) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.59]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.59]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) [catalina.jar:7.0.59]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [catalina.jar:7.0.59]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) [catalina.jar:7.0.59]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [catalina.jar:7.0.59]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.59]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950) [catalina.jar:7.0.59]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421) [catalina.jar:7.0.59]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.59]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.59]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.59]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_102]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_102]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.59]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_102]
Caused by: org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.NoSuchClientException: Unknown client mobile_ios
        at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.oauth2.client.impl.DefaultClientDetailsService.loadClient(DefaultClientDetailsService.java:59) ~[webservicescommonsserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.oauth2.client.impl.DefaultClientDetailsService.loadClientByClientId(DefaultClientDetailsService.java:42) ~[webservicescommonsserver.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(ClientDetailsUserDetailsService.java:44) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:102) ~[spring-security-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        ... 54 more

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I had for Hybris 5.6 :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Defaults</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CURRENT_CATALOG_VERSION_ATTRIBUTE_KEY</key>
        <string>Online</string>
        <key>USE_CACHE_ATTRIBUTE_KEY</key>
        <string>true</string>
        <key>CURRENT_STORE_ATTRIBUTE_KEY</key>
        <string>electronics</string>
        <key>CURRENT_CATALOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEY</key>
        <string>electronicsProductCatalog</string>
        <key>REST_URL_ATTRIBUTE_KEY</key>
        <string>rest/v2</string>
        <key>CURRENT_ROOT_CATEGORY_KEY</key>
        <string>1</string>
        <key>YULM00574455A</key>
        <string>empty</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Debug</key>
    <dict>
        <key>HOST_ATTRIBUTE_KEY</key>
        <string>xx.xx.xx.xx</string>
        <key>PORT_ATTRIBUTE_KEY</key>
        <string>9002</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Release</key>
    <dict>
        <key>HOST_ATTRIBUTE_KEY</key>
        <string>xx.xx.xx.xx</string>
        <key>PORT_ATTRIBUTE_KEY</key>
        <string>9002</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I remember that I had to add the **YULM00574455A** key to make it work.

Comment: What this key mean (Will try and let you know) and also is the URL https://<IP-Address>:9002/authorizationserver/oauth/token correct (this is automatically set when i run the app)? My Site address is https://<IP-Address>:9002/yb2bacceleratorstorefront/?site=powertools when accessed through browser. I don't see defaultTestUser in your XML?

Comment: I had updated my question which include the BASIC_AUTH constant being used if that helps.

Comment: Are you able to login from Postman (or other) using this user ? When you try to login do you see the attempt in Hybris's log ?

Comment: Can you help me how to call this using postman? On Postman i get "message": "Bad client credentials". I will update the question

Comment: Updated with Hybris Console Error. I had tried "client_id" as both "mobile_android" and "mobile_ios". Please let me know what i am missing.

Comment: I was reading about that oAuth is required in Hybris 6.0 and that has to be configured separately. Do i need to setup that?

Comment: Do you have *ycommercewebservices* in your local extensions (or a custom implementation of it) ? The authorization server endpoint comes from the *oauthauthorizationserver* extension. Check that this is loaded on your system.

Comment: How can we add this? Don't have much experience on this. Is there a step-by-step guide for this?

Comment: Have a look at : https://help.hybris.com/6.1.0/hcd/8c91f3a486691014b085fb11c44412ff.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122893/discussion-between-arun-gupta-and-benoit-vanalderweireldt).

Answer (score 0):

Use this as Authorization Header

**Basic bW9iaWxlX2FuZHJvaWQ6c2VjcmV0**

[image]

**And Parameters**

[image]